# Create Non Duplicate User Name in Database

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to create a username for my website based on their first name and their last name. (FirstName.LastName) If a person has the same first name and last name then they would have the same username. I am trying to make it so that if they do have the same name it would just add an incrementing number. Here is what I have so far.

```
$sq = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$quer = mysqli_query($conn, $sq);
$userName = '';
$mod = 1;
$foundUser = false;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quer)){
    if($row['UserName'] == ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName']))){
        while($foundUser = false){  
            if($row['UserName'] == ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName'])) . $mod){
                $mod = $mod + 1;
                echo 'hitting mod';
            }else{
                $userName = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName'])) . $mod;
                $foundUser = true;
                echo 'last else';
            }
        }
    }                       
}
```

This isn't currently populating the $userName variable and I don't know why. I have a while loop. None of the echos are being hit which is weird. There is definitely multiple users with the same username already in my table.

Comment: I would suggest searching the database for the username first, rather than getting all users and looping them. As your database grows this will slowly becoming less and less manageable. E.g. SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = Firstname.Lastname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$userName` only assign if it is exist in database. You need add `else` after first `if` condition.

```
if($row['UserName'] == ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName']))){
    while($foundUser = false){
        if($row['UserName'] == ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName'])) . $mod){
            $mod = $mod + 1;
            echo 'hitting mod';
        }else{
            $userName = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName'])) . $mod;
            $foundUser = true;
            echo 'last else';
        }
    }
} else {
    $userName = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName']));
}
```

You can search the username in database first, rather than getting all users and looping them. This is my suggestion:

```
$userName = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['fName'])) . '.' . ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['lName']));
$sq = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE '".$userName."%'";
$quer = mysqli_query($conn, $sq);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($quer);

if($count > 0) {
    $userName = $userName . $count; // or $userName = $userName . ($count + 1)
}
```

Comment: It works. You needed to change the equals sign to the 'LIKE' when using wildcards though.

Answer (score 0):

If in your query using `where username like UserName like '".$userName."%'"`

**what happen if we this scenario ?**

- user `A` register with `$_POST['fName']=John` & `$_POST['lName']=Doe` (set JohnDoe as username).
- User `B` register with `$_POST['fName']=John` & `$_POST['lName']=Doei` (set johnDoei as username).
- User `C` register with `$_POST['fName']=John` & `$_POST['lName']=Doe` (count of users that username is like `JohnDoe` is two row, set 'JohnDoe2' as usrename)

you have `JohnDoe3` for User `C` username, but shoud get `JohnDoe1 or JohnDoe2` username . any user that begin name with `JohnDoe` affect count of rows, not just users that is `JohnDoe+{number}`.

**Another scenario that cause have duplicate username :**

- user `A` register with `$_POST['fName']=John` & `$_POST['lName']=Doe` (set JohnDoe as username).
- User `B` register with `$_POST['fName']=John` & `$_POST['lName']=Doe2` (set johnDoei as username).
- User `C` register with `$_POST['fName']=John` & `$_POST['lName']=Doe` (count of users that username is like `JohnDoe` is two row, set `JohnDoe2` as usrename but already taken by user user `B`, now you have duplicate rows, and if want to use `username+(count+1)` as username, assume user `B` have `$_POST['lName']=Doe3`, for user `C` you setting `JohnDoe3` as username and again have duplicate username in your table).

My suggestion is get `username` from user when registering, and search just user stetted `username` in database and show error to user that try another `username` if taken already.

> One note :  You should using parameter binding for prevent sql injection, see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)